# LIKE two different cells from different tables SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two columns in two different tables. They can both contain data thats similar. For example column what would have `stack` and column 2 would have `stack overflow` in. The data varies from line to line though, What i want to do is do a LIKE to return only the rows that match so if each one has the same word in (even if there are other words) then it returns the value. I I've tried a few like's with % but cant seem to get it?

Comment: Can you post your query as well as DB schema ?

Comment: You can probably link them fairly easily as long as one will always entirely contain the other, if not it gets VERY difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much about sql-server, so i won't be able to write down a code, but i think this steps would help you solvle the problem.

You need to split the values to words in both tables, you might need to a create a function for that purpose. This link might help you with that [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

Then join the tables, and write down a filtering statement of where clause saying;

```
t1.words in (t2.words) or t2.words in (t1.words)
```

SOME|ANY keywords might help you with that.